# codeIgniter Facebook Login Error on IE

Tags: php, facebook

I'm developing a website, which has facebook authentication 3.1. In all other browsers login is working successfully but on IE it returns 0.

The URL is: http://gou_c.mymoje.com/

Actually the facebook->getuser() returns the 0, I tried but no result.

Does anyone know what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably be the old third-party-cookies problem again. Search for that or similar terms; usually sending a P3P header helps.